# IE10 Materialize waves-effect event.target become waves-ripple, not the element i click

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, internet-explorer-10, materialize

I have a "div" with waves-effect from materialize binded click event of alert "click div".

In this "div" contain "i tag" binded click event of alert "click i".

In IE11, firefox, and chrome, when i click on "i tag" will correctly fire the click event alert "click i", As expected.
As I click the "div" will fire click event that alert "click div".

Only in IE10, when I click the "i tag" it fire alert "click div" which is click event from the "div".
It should alert "click i".

Anyone could save me?

I have stimulate the scenario in jsBIn: http://jsbin.com/zodokezoqe/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: It looks like bootstrap's div-click captures the click event and doesn't let it go down to the inner  tag.

Comment: It is not bootstrap's div, it is waves-ripple effect div create by materialize.js